# How to change the Header info (text) in NSIS at run time?

Tags: nsis

I am using NSIS i.e., null soft to create a windows installer. All working fine, but I need to change the header info text while installer is running.

**For example:**

In header info Now I am getting as follows,

```
Installing, Please wait while...
```

But I need to change this info or text like `Please wait...` or any text. Herewith I have attached the screenshot and marked in red color. Please suggest some solution.

[image]

Comment: The Modern UI documentation has a list of all the attributes you can change, all you had to do was look there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
!include MUI.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "Blah blah"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Sub blah blah"
#!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_TEXT "Blah blah completed" ; You only need this if MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES is the last page
#!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_SUBTEXT "Sub blah blah"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
```

*Edit:* And to change it during the install process:

```
Section
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Hello" "world"
Sleep 3333
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Still" "there?"
Sleep 3333
SectionEnd
```

Comment: yes its correct, what you have gave above is for starting and ending the header info comes, in between these two i want one more header info to be included. Is it possible?

Comment: !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "123" "456"